# I am using jquery next and cosest options to select only one element but this applies classes to every element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML menu is like this

```
<div style="margin-top: 200px; width: 140px; text-align: left; line-height: 20px;">
    <div class="lmenu">Home</div>
    <div class="lmenu">About Us</div>
    <div class="lmenu parent">Our Services
        <div class="subparent">
            Event Management
                <div class="child">
                Categories
                </div>
                <div class="child">
                Providing Facilities
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subparent">
            Rental
            <div class="child">
                AVEquipments
            </div>
            <div class="child">
                Other Services
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subparent">
            Exhibition Stalls 
            <div class="child">
                Standard Stall
            </div>
            <div class="child">
                Designed Stalls
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lmenu parent">About Us
        <div class="subparent">
            Our Company
            <div class="child">
                Categories
            </div>
            <div class="child">
                Our Team
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I am using jQuery on mouseover and mouseout functions to view sub items. but when I hovering only one menu item every sub menu is going to visible.

here is my jquery

```
var $sub_itmes;
$(".parent").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $sub_itmes = $(".lmenu").next().find(".subperent");
        $sub_itmes.css({
            "display": "block",
        });
        $sub_itmes.animate({
            "opacity": 1
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $sub_itmes = $(".lmenu").next().find(".subperent");
        $sub_itmes.css({
            "display": "none",
        });
        $sub_itmes.animate({
            "opacity": 0
        });
    }
});

$(".subperent").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $sub_itmes = $(this).closest('.lmenu').find(".chilld");
        $sub_itmes.css({
            "display": "block",
        });
        $sub_itmes.animate({
            "opacity": 1
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $sub_itmes = $(this).closest('.lmenu').find(".chilld");
        $sub_itmes.css({
            "display": "none",
        });
        $sub_itmes.animate({
            "opacity": 0
        });
    }
});
```

I can't find where I'm wrong.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your find was doing this

1. from current element find `.lmenu` (which is the parent)
2. now find all .chilld inside top parent (which will find all of them)
3. show/hide them

By using the syntax `$(query,scope)` you can find an element that is within the current selection.

```
var $sub_itmes;
$(".parent").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $sub_itmes = $('.subperent',this);
        $sub_itmes.fadeIn('slow');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $sub_itmes = $('.subperent',this);
        $sub_itmes.fadeOut('slow');
    }
});

$(".subperent").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $sub_itmes = $('.chilld',this);
        $sub_itmes.fadeIn('slow');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $sub_itmes = $('.chilld',this);
        $sub_itmes.fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3Asr/)

On a side note take a look at [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin, It will ignore a quick mouse over but activate only when it seems the user wanted to do so.